# Wget a series of files in order

Tags: wget

How do you download a series of files with wget like so:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?file=1
http://www.example.com/index.php?file=2
http://www.example.com/index.php?file=3
...
http://www.example.com/index.php?file=500
```

Comment: simultaneously or one by one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*wget* supports downloading more than a file with a single command. This means that you can take advantage of your shell features like so:

```
wget http://www.example.com/index.php?file={1..500}
```

If your URLs are in a file (one URL per line) or on standard input, you can also use *wget*'s `-i` option.

Comment: If the numbers have padding, you can also do it this way: `wget http://www.example.com/index.php?file={001..500}`

Answer (score 4):

Place all the urls in a file, one url per line. Let's call it file.txt.

Then place the code inside another file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url; do
   wget "$url"
done < file.txt
```

save the file at the same directory file.txt and execute it through a terminal.

If you would like to download the files simultaneously, then simply add an & after the `wget "$url"` command (at the same line)